# ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I get

> "ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be
>   0."

on random calendaristic data.

I run the following query:

```
insert into TEMP_TBL
SELECT COUNT(ea.employee_rk) AS no_logins,
  ea.country_cd,
  ea.nsb_department,
  ea.employee_id,
  NULL,
  NULL
FROM EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY ea
  JOIN employee_activity_ded ead
    ON ead.employee_act_ver_sk=ea.employee_act_ver_sk
  JOIN employee_start_end ese
    ON ese.employee_id    = ea.employee_sk
   AND ea.ACTIVITY_DT>=ese.START_REV
   AND ea.ACTIVITY_DT <ese.end_rev
WHERE TRUNC(ea.ACTIVITY_DT) BETWEEN to_date('01-AUG-2017','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('31-AUG-2017','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');


DESC TEMP_TBL;

VALUE_SEC        NUMBER
COUNTRY_CD    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
NSB_DEPARTMENT         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
EMPLOYEE_RK  VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)
ACCESS_DAY      DATE
ACCESS_TIME    DATE


DESC employee_start_end;

EMPLOYEE_VERSION_SK              NUMBER(20,0)
EMPLOYEE_SK   NUMBER(20,0)
START_REV         DATE
END_REV             DATE
EMPLOYEE_ID   VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)
```

`EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY` has a big number of columns, but what it's important:

```
ea.ACTIVITY_DT       DATE
```

This error occurs on random data within the tables. What is strange is that when I add `TO_DATE` to `ese.START_REV` and to `ese.END_REV` the error doesn't appear anymore.

Both `ese.START_REV` and to `ese.END_REV` have `DATE` as datatype.

After I add `TO_DATE` the same query runs without errors:

```
insert into TEMP_TBL
SELECT COUNT(ea.employee_rk) AS no_logins,
  ea.country_cd,
  ea.nsb_department,
  ea.employee_id,
  NULL,
  NULL
FROM EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY ea
  JOIN employee_activity_ded ead
    ON ead.employee_act_ver_sk=ea.employee_act_ver_sk
  JOIN employee_start_end ese
    ON ese.employee_id    = ea.employee_sk
   AND ea.ACTIVITY_DT>=to_date(ese.START_REV)
   AND ea.ACTIVITY_DT <to_date(ese.end_rev)
WHERE TRUNC(ea.ACTIVITY_DT) BETWEEN to_date('01-AUG-2017','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('31-AUG-2017','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Oh my code ! Edit your post with snippets it's easier to read please

Comment: `to_date('01-AUG-2017','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` Your input string does not have the `hour:minute:second` components.

Comment: But if you ignore that part with the hour:minute:second, do you dea any reason  why the error disaper when i add to_date to start and end dev?

Answer (score 4):

**[TL;DR]** Given your stated data types, adding `TO_DATE` should make no difference and your original query should have worked. Check that the tables you are describing have the correct owner (and you are not describing a similarly named table belonging to a different owner) and have the data types you state because the issue would make sense if one of them was a string (but does not make sense if they are all dates).

> What is strange is that when I add to_date to `ese.START_REV` and to `ese.START_REV` the error doesn't appear anymore.

This implies that somehow the query is comparing the columns using a string comparison semantics and is implicitly casting your dates to strings but there is no obvious column which would cause this to happen since you state `ea.ACTIVITY_DT`, `ese.START_REV` and `ese.END_REV` are all of the `DATE` data type and should just compare using date comparison semantics and not string comparison semantic.

Looking at your modified query:

```
JOIN employee_start_end ese
    ON ese.employee_id    = ea.employee_sk
   AND ea.ACTIVITY_DT>=to_date(ese.START_REV)
   AND ea.ACTIVITY_DT <to_date(ese.end_rev)
```

Given you stated `ese.START_REV` and `ese.end_rev` are of the `DATE` data type, this is effectively:

```
JOIN employee_start_end ese
    ON ese.employee_id  = ea.employee_sk
   AND ea.ACTIVITY_DT  >= TO_DATE(
                            TO_CHAR(
                              ese.START_REV,
                              NLS_DATE_FORMAT
                            ),
                            NLS_DATE_FORMAT
                          )
   AND ea.ACTIVITY_DT   < TO_DATE(
                            TO_CHAR(
                              ese.end_rev,
                              NLS_DATE_FORMAT
                            ),
                            NLS_DATE_FORMAT
                          )
```

Where `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is given by:

```
SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
```

This should make zero difference to the query as you are converting from a date to a string and back to a date using the same format model in both conversions.

> I get the `ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0.`

This would probably be from an implicit conversion from a string value to a date where the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` does not match the format of the string value - again, it only makes sense of one of your columns is a string and not a date.

One other place where the issue could occur is in the `INSERT` statement if the order you are presenting the columns does not match the expected order. Try adding the column names to the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TBL(
  VALUE_SEC,
  COUNTRY_CD,
  NSB_DEPARTMENT,
  EMPLOYEE_RK,
  ACCESS_DAY,
  ACCESS_TIME,
)
SELECT COUNT(ea.employee_rk) AS no_logins,
       ea.country_cd,
       ea.nsb_department,
       ea.employee_id,
       NULL,
       NULL
FROM   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE TRUNC(ea.ACTIVITY_DT) BETWEEN to_date('01-AUG-2017','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('31-AUG-2017','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Your input date format '01-AUG-2017' doesn't match the format specified 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'.

Comment: I added that in a comment on the question - however unless the format model is prefixed with `FX`, which the OP has not done, then the missing time component will be ignored and it will not throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

I user procedure, its run ok.

```
and AUTH_DT between to_date(to_char(to_date(pv_ngaybc),'YYYY-MM-DD') ||' ' || pv_from ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
            and to_date(to_char(to_date(pv_ngaybc),'YYYY-MM-DD') ||' ' || pv_to,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```